# Kubernetes in-cluster authentication

Tags: python, kubernetes, azure-aks

it seems that my AKS cluster is unable to perform basic requests to the k8s api, i.e. using the in-cluster token for the pods. Everything works fine when I use the same code from my local machine, i.e. with `config.load_kube_config` .

I am using the python k8s client 11.0.0, and I am loading the configuration through `config.load_incluster_config()`. I get the following error:

`HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}`

when trying to simply list my pods (using `client.list_namespaced_pod`). I also tried to perform a raw get request, but same result.

I tried to extend the cluster role to specifically access the resources, here my clusterrole and clusterrolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: clusterrolename
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: clusterrolebindingname
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: clusterrolename
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: mynamespace
```

but I have always the same result.

The same approach does not work equally on linux and windows nodes.

The use of the very same approach was successful before on linux machine (pure linux cluster).

Could it be related to the SDK version?
Could it be something different in the cluster?
Does anyone know how I could retrieve a list of the authorisation for any specific ServiceAccount?

Answer (score 1):

You can check specific permission of a service account in a specific namespace using below command

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:default -n mynamespace
```

If the above command returns `no` that means the service account does not have right RBAC.

To list all permission of a service account use

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:default
```

To know more use `kubectl auth can-i -h`

Answer (score 1):

the pod had indeed the necessary rights. The error was in the wrong initialisation of the api_client instance, which I performed separately just calling client.Configuration().

I solved the problem avoiding to initialise the api_client instance, and importing the one directly from client.CoreV1Api.